# The Ubuntu 64-bit version is only for AMD processors?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04

Downloading Ubuntu 9.04, 64-bit version at

> http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download

using the MIT Media Lab location will lead to downloading a file

> http://ubuntu.media.mit.edu/ubuntu-releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso

it seems that the file is for AMD processors?  Can it be used for the Intel processors too?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is very confusing naming, but AMD64 (used to be called X86-64) as an instruction set standard is also being implemented by Intel 64-bit processors (except for the Itanium line of server CPUs, those use IA64).

So, yes, you can run it on Intel, too.

Check out the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) for more details (including a list of supported processors)

Comment: As far as I know AMD has been the first vendor for x86 desktop CPUs which introduced 64bit support. According to Wikipedia "„... called x86-64 (later branded AMD64).”"

Answer (score 1):

AMD64 and x86_64 *should* be the same.

The *other* 64 bit architecture is ia64, as far as I know.

Comment: Actually, there are a few others.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit